# How to track / inventory large number of files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[listObjectsv2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) API call is used to get the list of objects in an S3 bucket.  Unfortunately, the listObjectsV2 call is limited to 1000 objects per call -- not particularly useful for buckets with millions of files.  The listObjectsv2 API method is particularly painful due to it only returning the objects in alpha order -- meaning if you are looking for 'most recent' files, you need to call the listObjectsv2 API with a continuationToken and work your way through every single file in the bucket matching your prefix before getting to your 'most recent file'.

So, [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) is the tool for dealing with filesets >1000 objects...  Unfortunately, S3 Inventory only 'runs' daily.  Efectively making it useless for situations where the real-time status of your files matters.  Though - perhaps I'm missing something here?

**What tool or mechanism exists to help with real-time listing of larger s3 bucket contents?**  Specifically, I have buckets with millions of files that include a device identifier an then the date (ie: foobar___2022-02-02T12:00:00Z) and the most common access pattern is needing to see the most-recent X number of files.  The second most common pattern is needing to see all files between date Y and date Z.

One option would be to put each filename/key into a DB row and then use that for listing objects and other queries.... but that seems janky and it significantly complicates the entire system - now needing to keep the DB 'in sync' with reality.  Surely, there is a tool or standard methodology for this relatively normal access pattern.

Comment: You say this is a relatively normal access pattern. Are you aware of any other file/object storage systems that provide immediate, real-time access to the most recent N files or the largest N files across the entire storage or other arbitrary queries? Without you having to build an indexed solution yourself, that is.

Comment: Related blog post: [Building and Maintaining an Amazon S3 Metadata Index without Servers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-maintaining-an-amazon-s3-metadata-index-without-servers/).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151212/suitable-aws-service-to-maintain-an-index-of-s3-objects

Comment: @jarmod - pulling the "most recent file from a list of a million files" using on-prem resources is trivial.  I'm not saying it's easy in S3 - I'm saying that the "I need the most recent X files" is a pretty basic access pattern and that I suspect I don't need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: If the requirement can't be met with S3 Inventory, which it sounds like it can't, then I think your best option is to find (see links above) or build a custom solution. If you have access to AWS through an SA, TAM or enterprise support then you might want to ask them to raise a feature request or +1 any existing feature request. It would be a very useful feature, I agree.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks - your links helped solidify that, janky-though-it-may-be, saving your file related data in a DB is probably the solution.